# Camera pose to environment Mapping

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, autoencoders

I would like to teach a model the environment of a room. I'm doing so by mapping a camera pose **(x, y, z, q<sub>0</sub>, q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>, q<sub>3</sub>)** to its corresponding image; where **x, y, z** represent location in Cartesian coordinates and **q<sub>n</sub>** represent quaternion orientation. I have tried numerous decoder architectures but I get blurry results with little or no details; as can be seen from the images below:

[image]
[image]

I am using Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 0.0001, and my network architecture is as follows:

- ReLU(fc(7, 2048))
- ReLU(fc_residual_block(2048, 2048))
- ReLU(fc_residual_block(2048, 2048))
- Reshape
- ReLU(ConvTransposed2D(in=128, out=128, filter_size=3, stride=2))
- ReLU(ConvTransposed2D(in=128, out=128, filter_size=3, stride=2))
- ReLU(ConvTransposed2D(in=128, out=128, filter_size=3, stride=2))
- ReLU(ConvTransposed2D(in=128, out=128, filter_size=3, stride=2))
- ReLU(ConvTransposed2D(in=128, out=1, filter_size=3, stride=2))

I have tried different learning rates, loss functions(MSE, SSIM) and even batch normalization. Is there something that I'm missing here?